# Workaround for outputting HDMI audio from PC to Onkyo TX-SR506 receiver

Tags: home-theater, audio

I bought a used **Onkyo TX-SR506** receiver after the seller told me it supports HDMI input. I connected it in the following setup:

- PC HDMI out ➡ receiver HDMI in
- receiver HDMI out ➡ TV HDMI in

Doing so I got both audio and video outputted to the TV, and I couldn't get the audio outputted via the receiver. 90 pages later in the instruction manual I come across this devastating paragraph -

[image]

Is there a workaround to this limitation? I really hoped to use only HDMI connections and avoid optical / analog audio inputs. I find it puzzling that a receiver would have a big "HDMI" logo on it (and 4 HDMI connections) - but will act as a "pass thru" device.

Thanks!!

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't a home improvement question.

Comment: Lots of discussion on this to be found, though. [For example](https://www.avforums.com/threads/cant-get-sound-through-hdmi-on-onkyo-sr506.853966/). I use an HDMI switch with optical/coaxial audio output for my older receiver. Sorry your plans fell through.

Comment: Thanks @isherwood, guess your'e right, I got the idea to post here after seeing [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/73958/connecting-tv-to-receiver-via-hdmi?newreg=ccf96b6b30614021b3a4e6db497bfc19). Mind if I ask which HDMI switch are you using?

Comment: [This one](https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=5557). Been using it for about 10 years with an early DLP HDTV and an Onkyo non-hdmi receiver. Works well with my Harmony Ultimate remote.

Comment: did you assign the input of the HDMI that you connected to to an input selector as the instructions specify?    ---       **"If you connect a video component to an HDMI IN, you 
must assign that input to an input selector. For example, 
if you connect your DVD player to HDMI IN 1, you 
must assign HDMI IN 1 to the DVD input selector.
By default, none of the HDMI inputs are assigned. The 
following input selectors can be assigned: DVD, 
VCR/DVR, CBL/SAT, AUX."**

Comment: there are boxes that split A/V from HDMI, which might be better/easier than looping back from the TV. some "converters", like hdmi/dvi might also include audio out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the audio out of your stereo but you cannot avoid at least one non-HDMI audio connection.

**Option 1: Follow the method in the OEM Manual**
Along with each HDMI input install a digital or analog audio input. Analog inputs are automatically associated with a device (DVD, DVR) but digital inputs must be associated with a device (p. 42 in manual).

This is the preferred method but requirs the most wires. Also your input device must have alternative audio outputs.

**Option 2: Route audio back from the TV**

Many TVs have a digital or analog speaker output. Use this as an input on your receiver. The catch here is you may not have a good way to select this input when you want it. On older receivers there was a Tape Monitor loop that would let you listent to Tape2 input while otherwise routing some other input out. It's not clear to me that your receiver is setup to do something like this. So then your TV out would have to be tied to a single HDMI input and you lose the capability of routing audio. Also you may find that there is a perceptable delay in the audio due processing by the Receiver + TV (but hopefully this won't be the case).

Comment: Thanks Stanwood. Looks like I'll get an rca-to-aux cable and go with option #1.